# How to Hide ":before" Psuedo selector with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

Does anyone know how to hide the CSS ':before' pseudo selector with JavaScript? I have two arrows I use that point to an invalide input field. The arrows are made with unicode and are displayed with the ":before" pseudo selector.  For some reason they are being displayed when the page loads.  They should be inheriting from the JavaScript "display = 'none';" They should be hidden, but the arrows are still showing up.

**JsFiddle Code Sample:**
http://jsfiddle.net/ryanjohnsond/nyytwqmy/2/

This class ".error-text-login:before {}" is not receiving the JavaScript command "display = 'none';

```
.error-text-login:before {
 content: '\0020 \21E1 \0020';
  vertical-align: bottom; 
 }


 else if (pswd != "" || lenPswd.length > 0){
 document.getElementById('passwordLogin').className = 'default';
 document.getElementById('pswd-error').innerHTML = "";
 document.getElementById('pswd-error').style.display = "none";
 }
```

Comment: just add to css class `.error-text-login` rule for _display_ like `display: none` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyytwqmy/3/)

Comment: Your code is incredibly inflexible and can be improved a lot. I warmly suggest you post it on [codereview.se] and request for a proper code review, you'll probably learn a lot.

Comment: @Grundy: Thanks! Funny. I had that originally for another version of the code, but it didn't work with that version; so I tried this current approach, thinking the JS would handle that: I figured the CSS display:none; would overwrite the JS dislay = "none";

Answer (score 6):

You have to use css

CSS:

```
.hide-before:before {
    display: none !important;
}
```

JS:

```
pswd-error.className += ' hide-before';
```